# How do i get next prayer time from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, momentjs

Im trying to get next upcoming prayer from array list using current time.

im using React native

```js
prayer = [
   {
    "name": "Fajr",
    "time": "2021-01-27T10:51:00.000000Z",
  },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Dhuhr",
    "time": "2021-01-27T17:08:00.000000Z",
  },
   {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Asr",
    "time": "2021-01-27T19:45:00.000000Z",
  },
   {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Maghrib",
    "time": "2021-01-27T22:07:00.000000Z",
  },
   {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Isha",
    "time": "2021-01-27T23:26:00.000000Z",
  },
]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried something yourself yet?

Comment: I tried some of method but not working at all.

Comment: As a general advice, SO users like to see your attempt and its result. We are not here to write your code, but to help you write your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that
`var json = JSON.parse(prayer); let time = json.time;`
I did not test this but this should work

Comment: i can display prayer time but i want to get near upcoming prayer using current time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript date object and calculate the difference between the current time and each date

*some rough code*:

```
const getDateObj = (time) => {
    let d = new Date(time)
    return d
}
let now = new Date()
let dif = getDateObj(prayer[0].time) - now;
let index = 0

for (let i = 0; i < prayer.length; i++) {
    const pray = prayer[i];
    const currentDif = (getDateObj(pray.time) - now)
    if ( currentDif < dif ){
        dif = currentDif;
        index = i
    }
}

console.log(prayer[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the next Prayer time you need to do the following steps as this example:

```
const getNextPrayer = () =>{
    //get current datetime in milliseconds
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    //Those variables will store the next prayer and its index
    var next ;
    var nextIndex ;
    //Loop through prayer array
    prayer.map((e,i)=>{
        //Convert prayer time to milliseconds
        var prayerTimeMilliseconds = new Date(e.time).getTime();
        //check if prayer time is not past
        if ((prayerTimeMilliseconds-now) >= 1){
          //get index of the smallest prayer time integer
          if (!next || (prayerTimeMilliseconds-now) < next){
                  next = prayerTimeMilliseconds-now
                  nextIndex = i
          }
        }
    })
    return nextIndex;
}
```

Full Example at [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/get-next-prayer-time)